# Proof of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ have a continuous derivative over all of $\mathbb{R}$. I want to prove
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty .
\end{equation}
*proof.* From the Mean Value Theorem, we can say that for all $x>0$, there exists $0<x_0 <x$ such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(x_0 ).
\end{equation}
Taking limits on both sides, we get
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x_0 ).
\end{equation}
The first limit on the LHS is $\infty$ from the hypothesis. The second limit on the LHS is $0$ because $f(0)$ is finite as $f'(0)$ exists. We get
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x_0 )=\infty
\end{equation}
where $x_0 <x$. For any $x_0 <x_1 \leq x$,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x_1 )=\infty
\end{equation}
because $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$. So, we get
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty. \blacksquare
\end{equation}
Is my proof correct?

Comment: Do you additionally want to assume the limit of $f'(x)$ exists? (If you don't, the statement isn't true)

Comment: $x_0$ is a function of $x$, which makes the argument problematic

Comment: @BrianMoehring Can you point out the error in the proof?

Comment: Without _some_ additional assumption, the statement is false, so any proof you give necessarily would be invalid.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Can it be proved that the existence of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ implies the existence of $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)$?

Comment: No.  Try going through your argument with $f(x) = x^2 + 2x\sin(x)$ to see which step fails.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$ is another counterexample

Comment: @Sgg8 We need to note (to avoid sidetracking) that your example is a counterexample to the claim in the comments, not the OP.

Comment: @BrianMoehring sure

Comment: I think an additional assumption that would make the proposition true is if $f$ is convex. Perhaps there is a weaker assumption than this that would make the proposition true - I'm not sure.

Comment: To answer your question, the expression $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f’(x_0)$ is totally meaningless. Write this out carefully with quantifiers.

Answer (score 7):

The statement that is intended to be proven is incorrect.

A counterexample is

$$f(x) = x^2 + \sin(x^2).$$

We have $f(x) \ge x^2-1$ and thus certainly $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}x = \infty$.

We also have $f'(x)=2x+2x\cos(x^2)$. Since $\cos(x^2)=-1$ has solutions that are arbitrairly large ($x_n=\sqrt{\pi+2\pi n},n \in \mathbb N$), we have $f'(x_n)=0$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = \infty$ is impossible. $\blacksquare$

The error in the proof is the one as pointed out by Andrew Zang in the comments: The values of $x_0$ you get in your construction depends on $x$, you will not reach every (large) $x$ in $[0,\infty)$.

Let's name your $x_0$ for a given $x$ as $y_x$ (to make the dependence on $x$ evident). Just as I have picked a special sequences $(x_n)$ with $f'(x_n)=0$ for my definition of $f$, you have picked a special sequence of values $(y_x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(y_x) = \infty$ for every $f$ that fufills the initial assumptions.

The existence of neither sequence is enough to  conclude that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$ or $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = \infty$. This can only be true if $\lim_{n\to\infty} f'(x_n)$ is the same for **every sequence** $(x_n)$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$. That we could find 2 such sequences with different limits for my example shows that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} f'(x_n)$ does not exist for my $f$.

Comment: Exactly. The statement is clearly not true (to me anyway). I don't see what's wrong with $f(x) = x^2 + \sin(x)$ as a slightly simpler counter-example.

Comment: Then you have $f'(x)=2x + \cos(x)$, which does fulfill $\lim f'(x) = \infty$, so your example is not a counter-example. In order to offset the $2x$ from the  derivation of $x^2$, you need to add a function that can as well get a large negative derivative.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was being sloppy.